# use tailwindcss to remove element from the dom AFTER its transition has happened

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, css-transitions, display

In my angular app I have implemented the common design of having the top menu disappear when the user is scrolling down on a mobile device by using tailwind css to apply these classes

`class="transition-all duration-300" [class.!h-0]="!isHeaderVisible"`

this is working great for me but i am running into the seemingly common issue that my top menu still exists in the dom, its just simply had its height set to 0. id love to also set the display property to none AFTER the transformation has happened but i dont see a way to do that. if i try and set `[class.!hidden]="!isHeaderVisible"` in addition to the above my menu just disappears and reappears immediately instead of taking the 300ms. I know this is happening because display hidden to visible is a binary value but is there a way to trigger it AFTER the height transition has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen when a [transition end](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event)

In your component, get the nativeElement

```
private el!: HTMLElement;
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
}
```

In ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.subs = fromEvent(this.el, 'transitionend')
      .pipe(filter((res: TransitionEvent) => res.propertyName == "height"))
      .subscribe((res: TransitionEvent) => {
        //here you can add a class or style to this.el
      });
}
```

In ngOnDestroy

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs && this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Sometime ago I made a directive to collapse a div like bootstrap. You can see in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-omrhwh?file=src%2Fcollapse.directive.ts) to inspiration

Comment: interesting, didnt know there was a transitioned event like this. will definitely attempt to make a directive that can do this. thanks for the idea!